# SQl count() help with a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-00904

I'm using this code:

```
  SELECT MACH_NO, 
         COUNT(MACH_NO) AS TOTAL_REPORTS
    FROM MAINTENANCE_LOG
GROUP BY MACH_NO;
```

...to retrieve some data which gives:

```
MACH_NO  TOTAL_REPORTS
----------------------
1        4
5        2
8        1
7        1
```

How can I retrieve only where total reports is bigger than three? I tried:

```
WHERE TOTAL_REPORTS > 3
```

...but it says

> ORA-00904: "TOTAL_REPORTS": invalid identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've used a `GROUP BY`, you should use `HAVING` rather than `WHERE`. You also need to explicitly use `COUNT(MACH_NO)` rather than your alias of `TOTAL_REPORTS`.

So use `HAVING COUNT(MACH_NO) > 3`, rather than `WHERE TOTAL_REPORTS > 3`.

```
SELECT MACH_NO, 
       COUNT(MACH_NO) AS TOTAL_REPORTS 
FROM MAINTENANCE_LOG 
GROUP BY MACH_NO
HAVING COUNT(MACH_NO) > 3;
```

Comment: Ive never used the having clause before, no wonder couldnt progress

Answer (score 1):

Use [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) CLAUSE

```
SELECT MACH_NO, COUNT(MACH_NO) AS TOTAL_REPORTS FROM MAINTENANCE_LOG GROUP BY MACH_NO HAVING TOTAL_REPORTS > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MACH_NO, COUNT(MACH_NO) AS TOTAL_REPORTS FROM MAINTENANCE_LOG GROUP BY MACH_NO
`having count(mach_no) > 3`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of WHERE TOTAL_REPORTS > 3, try WHERE COUNT(MACH_NO) > 3.